# Is this documentation for the R 'psych' package ICC() function incorrect?

Tags: r, psychometrics, intraclass-correlation

I am not a statistician, but from my reading about various types of intraclass correlation measures, ICC(2,1) (Shrout and Fleiss nomenclature) is a measure of absolute agreement sensitive to additive bias, whereas ICC(3,1) is a measure of consistency (insensitive to additive bias). However, the documentation [for the R 'psych' package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/psych.pdf) ICC function states the following:

> ICC1 is sensitive to differences in means between raters and is a
> measure of absolute agreement. **ICC2 and ICC3 remove mean differences
> between judges**, but are sensitive to interactions of raters by judges.
> The difference between ICC2 and ICC3 is whether raters are seen as
> fixed or random effects.

Emphasis mine. The other statements in the passage, as far as I know, are correct. Is this documentation incorrect?

Comment: Seems correct to me. ICC2 and ICC3 do not measure absolute agreement, and can still be high if judges differ in their means mostly. Just like the correlation between X and X+10 is one, because only the means of X and X+10 differ.

Comment: @MarjoleinFokkema I am saying that ICC2 between X and Y is *not* high when Y = X+10, because ICC2 does measure absolute agreement. At least that is the behavior I have observed from the Python implementation I'm using (https://pingouin-stats.org/), which has been tested against the R psych package.

Comment: I might have responded too fast. I think you have a point about ICC2. The part you boldfaced should only refer to ICC3?

Comment: @MarjoleinFokkema yes, I think it should only refer to ICC3. It's a little confusing because ICC2 and ICC3 are different in two ways - ICC2 is random effects, agreement; ICC3 is mixed effects, consistency. To add to the confusion, apparently random/agreement and mixed/agreement has the *same formula*.

Comment: The formulas for ICC1 and ICC3 in the ICC documentation from psych do coincide with the formulas in Shrout and Fleiss (1979) (http://rokwa.x-y.net/Shrout-Fleiss-ICC.pdf) on p. 423. So perhaps confusing, but correct; S&F79 also mention this "An important practical implication is that for a given population of targets, the observed value of BMS [between-targets mean square] in a Case 1 design tends to be larger than that in a Case 2 or Case 3 design." This does not shed light on your original remark though.

Comment: Hi, can I ask, if I want to calculate test-retest reliability using ICC, then do I need to get the sum of scores of item response? Instead of the individual item score?